# Evaluating $\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{ \ln(\cos x - y^2)}{x^2+2y^2}$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

How can I compute such a limit:
$$\lim_{(x,y) \to(0,0)} \frac{ \ln(\cos x - y^2)}{x^2+2y^2}$$ ?

Lets first check if the iterated limits are equal. We have:

$$\lim_{x \to 0} \lim_{y \to 0} \frac{\ln(\cos x-y^2)}{x^2+2y^2}=-\frac{1}{2}=\lim_{y \to 0} \lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos x-y^2)}{x^2+2y^2}$$

So if $ \lim_{(x,y) \to (0, 0)}\frac{\ln(\cos x-y^2)}{x^2+2y^2}$ exists, it is equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$.

Using L'Hopital's rule I proved also that if $y=ax$ then

$$\lim_{x \to 0}\frac{\ln(\cos x - a^2x^2)}{x^2+2a^2x^2}=-\frac{1}{2}$$.

And here I have a problem - I still don't know if this limit exists or not. I don't see prove that it exists, but I also can't find a sequence converges to $0$ on which this limit is not equal to $-\frac{1}{2}$. Could you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit does exist. Using the Maclaurin expansion of $\cos x$ we find that $\cos x-y^2=1-(1/2)(x^2+2y^2)+o(x^2)$.

It follows that $\ln(\cos x-y^2)=-(1/2)(x^2+2y^2)+o(x^2+2y^2)$.

Comment: You omitted $o(x^2)$, because $\frac{o(x^2)}{x^2+2y^2} \le \frac{o(x^2)}{x^2} \to 0$, so $o(x^2)=o(x^2+2y^2)$. That's right?

Comment: Yes, one reason. And anyway the error in the log is $o(x^2+2y^2)$.